Blazor server not bringing service data when clicked twice
I have a blazor server application with a service base backend (no API).
I'm not posting the real code due to company policies, so I provided the following example.
I have a button that when clicked triggers a method that searchs for an element with an id.
Index.razor
<MudNumericField HideSpinButtons="true"
                 @bind-Value="ElementNumber"
                 Label="Element number"
                 Variant="Variant.Text"
                 Required
                 id="element-number-id"
                 OnKeyUp="OnEnterPressed"
                 RequiredError="Cannot be empty"
                 Placeholder="Type a number" />

<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled"
         Color="Color.Primary"
         id="element-search-btn"
         OnClick="OnSearchElement"
         Disabled="@_loading_btn">Search</Mudbutton>


    @code {
        public IEnumerable<ElemDTO>? Elems { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ElemDTO>? CopyElems { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ElemDTO>? TmpElems { get; set; }
        public int? ElementNumber {get;set;} = default!;

        public async void OnSearchElement() {
           TmpElems = await _service.getElementByNumber(ElementNumber)
           Elems = CopyElems = FormatElement(TmpElems);
           await InvokeAsync(() => this.StateHasChanged());
          // Elems is used for rendering the collection on a table.
        }

         public IEnumerable<ElemDTO>? FormatElement(IEnumerable<ElemDTO>? elems) {
             // this method modifies the elems collection
              elems.FirstOrDefault().Prop1 = false;
             // it overrides some of their properties.
             return elems;
         }
   }

This example above is working just fine for the first time I click on the button. The issue appears when I click again the Mudbutton to search. It triggers the service call as expected (I debugged step by step and it is going across all the expected paths) but the weird thing is that the collection remains in a modified state, like the one shown in the example: Prop1 remains false and the original value (the one from the database) is true. Is this caching the search results from the previous query in some way? Any ideas??

How is it possible? Do you mean the "TmpElems" prop1 you get again   turned to be false? Even if there's caching, but you haven't modify any value in "TmpElems" before. You only modify "Elems" and "CopyElems".

that's right, when TmpElems = _service.GetElementsByNumber(ElementNumber) is called for the second time, after clicking on the button, TmpElems remains modified. I debugged FormatElement step by step and it's having this weird behaviour. Remember that this previously modified array is the one that is assigned to Elems and CopyElems.
If I reload the page, it works properly. Maybe I can force a refresh of the page, but I don't think is a better solution. The issue is when I click twice the button without reloading.
